# SQL Good Practices: NOT IN vs <>

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a performance difference between `NOT IN` and `<>` in the `WHERE` clause? What is considered a good practice and when?

Scenario:

```
NOT IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

vs

```
<> 'a' AND
<> 'b' AND
<> 'c' AND
<> 'd'
```

Other than simpler code, is there ever a case to use `NOT IN` over a bunch of `<>` lines?

When should I use 1 over the other for performance reasons?

Comment: Edited my post to clarify

Comment: So when you inspected the execution plan was it any different?

Comment: That's a good point, I should have checked that first. My mistake, I forgot to do this.

Comment: There is an issue with a _long_ list of values and `in` as explained in the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks).

Comment: If you inspect the execution plan, you will see `NOT IN` is actually converted to `<>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they are equivalent in SQL Server.  However, I recommend `NOT IN` because it is more concise and less prone to error.

In some databases, it *can* make a difference.  For instance, MySQL sorts `IN` lists for a binary search (and I assume it does the same with `NOT IN` lists as well).  However, I don't think SQL Server has such an optimization.

Answer (score 2):

They are exactly same. No difference.

But, if any NULL values are coming into picture, then NOT EXISTS will be the right choice.

[Read more on NOT IN Vs NOT EXISTS](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/02/18/not-exists-vs-not-in/)